# Rails HTML Request Render JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my controller, I'm supporting HTML and JSON in my `index` method by doing:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
```

When pulling it up in the browser, it renders in HTML naturally. However, when I do a curl call with content-type being `application/json` to the `/user` resource (since it's the index method), I still get the HTML as a response.

How can I get the JSON as a response? What else do I need to specify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should  append `.json` to the requested url, provided format is defined in the path in `routes.rb`. This is default when using `resources`. For example, `rake routes` should give you something like:

```
show_user GET    /users/:id(.:format) users#show
```

To get user in HTML

```
curl  http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

To get user in JSON:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/users/1.json
```

Comment: @Darksy: you can also check it in browser http://localhost:3000/users/1.json using someting like this.